# groovy or pipleline script to send notification to Slack from Jenkins

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, webhooks, slack

I need to use Webhooks to send notification to slack from jenkins. I am well aware of notifier plugin, but for that I would require access in Slack which client doesnt want to provide. They have provided Webhook url details. Anyone has any idea how i can post notification(Job name, link, user who ran it, and cause of error(if)) to slack

Comment: Try using `curl`.

Answer (score 3):

As Matt commented, we use curl to do this. We have it in a shared library and invoke it from the pipeline, sample code below. Room for improvement, but should get you going.

```
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

def sendBuildNotification(sharedVars, String buildStatus = 'STARTED', String slackHeading = 'BUILD') {

    // Build status of null means success.
    buildStatus = buildStatus ?: 'SUCCESS'
    // Default image is normal Jenkins
    image =':jenkins:'
    long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000

    // Determine Color
    def color
    if (buildStatus == 'STARTED' || buildStatus == 'ABORTED') {
        color = '#D4DADF' // Grey
    } else if (buildStatus == 'SUCCESS') {
        color = '#319b20' // Green
    } else if (buildStatus == 'UNSTABLE' || buildStatus == 'INPUT REQUIRED') {
        color = '#ff8316' // Yellow
    } else {
        color = '#f44242' // Red
        image=':badjenkins:'
    }

    // Create JSON Payload
    def json = JsonOutput.toJson(
        [
            username: "${slackHeading} ${buildStatus}",
            channel: "${insertChannel}",
            icon_emoji: image,
            attachments: [[
                title: "Job: ${env.JOB_NAME}/${env.BUILD_NUMBER}",
                title_link: "${env.BUILD_URL}console",
                fallback: "Jenkins Job Alert - ${buildStatus} - ${env.JOB_NAME}", 
                color: color,
                fields: [[
                    title: "Repository",
                    value: "<${insert SCM Host}/${env.GIT_REPO_NAME}|${env.GIT_REPO_NAME}>",
                    short: true
                ],[
                    title: "Branch",
                    value: "<${insert SCM Host}/${env.GIT_REPO_NAME}/tree/${BRANCH_NAME}|${BRANCH_NAME}>",
                    short: true
                ],[
                    title: "Last Commit",
                    value: "<${insert SCM Host}/${env.GIT_REPO_NAME}/commit/${sharedVars.gitCommit}|${sharedVars.gitCommit}>",
                    short: false
                ]],
                footer: "<@${env.BUILD_USER_ID}>",
                ts: epoch,
                mrkdwn_in: ["footer", "title"],
            ]]
        ]
    )

    try {
        // Post to Slack
        sh "curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '${json}' ${slackURL} --max-time 5"
    } catch (err) {
        echo "${err} Slack notify failed, moving on"
    }
}
```